# How to programmatically 'load' things in iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization, progress-bar

In my app, I have noticed that it will run slowly for the first few seconds of running because objects are still being initialized, drawn to the screen, etc. How do I load these objects and create a bar to show the progress of the loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a loading screen.
You can use different threads and detach threads. 
Alternatively you can use a `UIActivityIndicatorView` or `UIProgressBar` to show that currently loading is on.

`UIActivityIndicatorView` basically is like when you start up your mac. A spinning circle.
`UIProgressBar` is a empty bar that fills up with blue as the loading increases.

A `UIProgressBar` has a variable called `progress` while you just send `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` messages to a `UIActivityIndicator`

To read more about these two, check the links below:

[Progress Bar Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Progress Bar Image](http://www.idevindex.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/UIDownloadBar.jpg)

[Activity Indicator Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)

[Activity Indicator GIF Image](http://getsetgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/ActivityIndicator.gif)

UPDATE TO YOUR QUESTION ON OTHER ANSWER:

What are you loading for? Does the class/object you are loading for have a delegate method? If you are saying

> still being initialized and drawn to the screen

Considering `object` below is one of your objects
You could say

```
if (object) {
// saying just 'object' asks if it is non-zero/valid
}
```

Also to check if DRAWN to the screen try:

```
    if([self.view.subviews containsObject:object])
```

or

```
if([object superview] == self.view)
```

or the method

```
-(BOOL)isDescendantOfView:(UIView *)view;
```

Return Value `YES` if the receiver is an immediate or distant subview of view or if view is the receiver itself; otherwise `NO`.

ALSO: when i say `self.view`, it doesn't have to be `self`, since loading view might be a different view. You could make an object to that other class and call that class instead of `self`. Like: `if([otherClass.object superview] == otherClass.view)`

You could also make an `update` method in the other class so you could say:

```
if([otherClass finishedLoading])
```

and then have this as the `update` method:

```
- (BOOL)finishedLoading {
return ([object superview] == self.view)
}
```

This is a lot to take in! Any other questions?

Comment: That helps alot, I think I will go with the approach of testing to see whether all of the subviews have been initialized. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"How do I load these objects" - there can be multiple way as per your need-

1. you can use concurrent threads to load thing.
2. You can go for lazy loading - first load those thing which needs to be show on first screen(considering you are loading couple of data which is not needed on first screen).
3. You can show a loading screen and let user know that loading is going on.

you can use a `UIActivityIndicator` or `UIProgressBar` to show that currently loading is on.

Comment: Say I displayed a loading screen, how would I know when everything had finished loading so I can stop displaying that screen?

Comment: @Fitzy - issue fixed or still some doubt?